# How to change iOS slider value through Appium/WebdriverIO

Tags: ios, react-native, appium, webdriver-io, xcuitest

I am testing my React Native app using Appium and WebdriverIO. Having difficulty in changing slider values.

Normally in XCUITest I can easily achieve this using the following code:

```
app.sliders["slider-red"].adjust(toNormalizedSliderPosition: 0)
```

How to do the equivalent in Appium/WebdriverIO? I read somewhere that I should call sendKeys(). I tried the following:

```
$('~slider-red').sendKeys(['0']);
```

But it is giving me the following error:

> invalid element state: Error Domain=com.facebook.WebDriverAgent Code=1 "The on-screen keyboard must be present to send keys"

It looks like sendKeys is for input fields, not for sliders!

Comment: Have you tried with setvalue? https://gitter.im/webdriverio/webdriverio/archives/2018/07/02

Comment: There are other options you may want to try. https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/213

Comment: `browser.setValue('~slider-red', 0);` gives this error: `TypeError: browser.setValue is not a function` - probably because I am not in the browser context and I am trying to test a native iOS widget.

Comment: The other solution looks like purely for a browser. In any case, I tried the very first step in it - `browser.moveTo(100, 100);` and again it gives me an error: `TypeError: browser.moveTo is not a function`. I even tried this statement in a browser context and it still gives me the same error! Wonder if the boilerplate I am using doesn't allow this: [appium-boilerplate](https://github.com/webdriverio/appium-boilerplate)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using mobile gestures, that Appium provides for running non-W3C standard commands. In you case, it is `mobile: selectPickerWheelValue` command, more details [here](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/ios/ios-xctest-mobile-gestures/#mobile-scroll):

```
const elementId = $(pickerwheel_locator).elementId
browser.execute('mobile: selectPickerWheelValue',
        {
            'order': 'next',
            'offset': 0.15,
            'element': elemId
        });
```

As far as I remember, it works like this

Comment: Thanks, @dmie. Your syntax was very close. In WebdriverIO, I was simply able to do `$('~slider-red').elementId` However after this calling browser.execute() generated this error: "invalid argument: The element is expected to be a valid Picker Wheel control. 'XCUIElementTypeSlider' was given instead". I finally tracked the problem down to [this issue](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/8264#issuecomment-294523926) in Appium repo. Unfortunately they think that it's an Apple bug and there's no resolution :-(